# REST API design guideline for tree structure

Tags: rest, user-interface

I am designing REST API for adding and retrieving tree kind of structure. The design is as follows

---

### UI

```
Tree Root - Header - # need to display total node weight and aggregated data
    - Node
        - Node
    - Node 
        - Node
        - Node

Node {
 int weight, 
 // large object
}
```

---

### API

```
GET:    /tree/{id}
```

returning tree only level 1 nodes

```
GET:    /tree/{treeid}/nodes/{nodeid}
```

returning child nodes

`POST:   /tree/{treeid}/node`

add/update new node

Can I return tree root with the header from here?

ideally, it(POST) should return the newly created resource.

To save two API calls (One to save Node and another for the header), can I return Node data along with header data?

Comment: Why would you need to do another `GET` request after the `POST`? Doesn't the client already have all the relevant information? Also, why is it important to save 1 http request? They can be pretty fast.

Comment: 1. While adding new node, weight will get associated with it which based on which header info will be recalculated.
2. Just to save another http request(for header data). is it good to return header data along with Node data ( or is it breaking any REST pattern?)

Comment: Makes sense. I wouldn't say it's really breaking the pattern, but maybe this is not (yet) an area you need to optimize for. If you are worried your HTTP requests are expensive, maybe you can make them faster and cheaper.